# Lubuntu 15.04 using a dell vostro 1510 WIFI problems

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, dell, 15.04

I'm new with ubuntu, I installed lubuntu 15.04 on my Dell vostro 15.04 but the wifi isn't working at all. I activated the drivers for the broadband still no wifi connection at all. I tried using a wifi stick, I found my wifi network, but after entering my password and a short connection progress I have to put in my password again and again and again. Nothing happens.
Hope for help
Thanks Jo

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Newuser, I also installed Lubuntu today on my Dell Vostro 1510 and I found a solution on this very helpful board! - This fixed my wireless issues!

I used a network cable connection and ran the following code below from my terminal:

***sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer***

restarted computer and it Worked Great! :-)